# jquery prevent scroll function on form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scrollto

I'm working on a single page rsvp site with scrolling content managed with jQuery. The site has different sections that are accessed through a horizontal menu at the top, calling the specific divs and scrolling to the content after the user has selected the menu item. Everything works fine except when the user goes to the rsvp form on mobile devices. When the user screen gets scrolled to that part, each time the user select the input area, the site scrolls to the top and I can't figure it out a way to avoid that behavior because it makes the form pretty useless. I'm not having this problem on the desktop.

This is the scroll script:

```
$( document ).scroll(function() { 
    console.log( Math.round( $(document).scrollTop()/$(window).height() ) )
    $('.site-slider').css( 'top',  -( $(window).height() * Math.round(
    $(document).scrollTop()/$(window).height() ) ) );
    $(".background-container")
      .css("perspective-origin", 
           '50% '+ ($(document).scrollTop()*.1)+"%");       
 });
```

i was thinking that add a preventdefault to the id that contains the form would help, or adding it to the input fields but nothing worked but it seems i cant find the way, was trying with something like this to avoid scroll on each input click with class "quieto"

```
$('.quieto').click(function(e) {
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I'm pretty new to javascript and jquery and been extensively searching for an answer. I will appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Comment: Not the issue but `event` and `e` are not the same, and returning will render any instruction that follows useless, which is why you don't see the error logged.

Comment: Regarding that `click` function, try moving the `return false;` statement to the end of the function, as the return statement should be the last statement in a function. Anything after it will not be executed.

Comment: i modified the click function to this: 
 $('#rsvp, .quieto, input').bind('touchmove', function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}); 

and it works just for the first input field because when i go to the second it automatically scrolls to the top :(